# Obtain data from sqlite Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, lifecycle, ionic-native

I have a problem with my code that when I go to look for the data that I have stored in SQLite these are executed at the end and I need them since these I need them to consume a service that will finally load the data on the screen.
I leave my code below:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { LoadingController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
 import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';
 import { Uid } from '@ionic-native/uid/ngx';
 import { EsqueletoServiceProvider } from '../../providers/no4get- 
 service/no4get-services';
 import { DatabaseServiceProvider } from '../../providers/database- 
 service/database-service';
 import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-general',
   templateUrl: './general.page.html',
   styleUrls: ['./general.page.scss'],
 })
 export class GeneralPage {
   listaCategorias: any;
   token: any;
   imei: string;
   cards: any;
   loading: any;
   datosTelefono: any;


   constructor(private loadingController: LoadingController,
     public esqueletoService: EsqueletoServiceProvider,
     public databaseService: DatabaseServiceProvider,
     public uid: Uid, 
     public androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions,
     public alertCtrl: AlertController,
     public platform: Platform
     ) 
   { 
     this.listaCategorias = "1";
     this.databaseService.getSesion(1).then(result => {
       this.token = result.valor;
     })
     .catch( error => {
       this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias","","Hubo un problema al obtener los 
       datos del usuario.");
     });

     this.databaseService.getSesion(2).then(result => {
       this.imei = result.valor;
     })
     .catch( error => {
       this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias","","Hubo un problema al obtener los 
       datos del usuario.");
     });
   }



 ionViewDidEnter()
   {
     this.platform.ready().then(() => { 
       let datos = { 
         idNoticias: 0, 
         token: this.token,
         imei: this.imei
       };

       this.LoaderNoticias();
       this.esqueletoService.CargarNoticiasGeneral(datos).then((result) => 
       {
         if (result != null) 
         {
           let codigoError = result.toString().split('|');

           if(codigoError[0] == "777")
           {
             this.loadingController.dismiss();
             this.cards = result;
           }
           else if (codigoError[0] == "305")
           {
             this.loadingController.dismiss();
             this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias","",codigoError[2]);
           }
           else if (codigoError[0] == "310")
           {
             this.loadingController.dismiss();
             this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias","",codigoError[2]);
           }
           else if(codigoError[0] == "315")
           {
             this.loadingController.dismiss();
             this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias","",codigoError[2]);
           }
           else if(codigoError[0] == "000")
           {
             this.loadingController.dismiss();
             this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias","","Estimado usuario, hubo un 
             error inesperado.");
           }   
         } else {
           this.loadingController.dismiss();
           this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias","","Estimado usuario, hubo un 
           error inesperado.");
         }
       }, (err) => {
         this.loadingController.dismiss();
         this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias","","Estimado usuario, hubo un error 
         inesperado.");
       });
     });
   }
```

Currently, when the `ionViewDidEnter ()` event is executed, it creates a variable called `data` that is where I want to send an array to my service, but the token and IMEI fields up to that point are `undefined`. By following the path to the code once the entire `ionViewDidEnter ()` event is executed, the code just allocates the data of the token and IMEI variables that are in the constructor.
The question is, how can I get this data to be obtained before the `ionViewDidEnter ()` event is executed?

My code is being executed in visual studio code and Ionic 4. I thank you in advance for all the possible help you can give me, while I will continue investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data relies on other async data then you just have to keep nesting it until you slowly go insane :P

Remove the code from your constructor and then put it all in the `ionViewDidEnter()` with nesting:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.listaCategorias = "1";
        this.databaseService.getSesion(1).then(result => {
            this.token = result.valor;

            this.databaseService.getSesion(2).then(result => {
                this.imei = result.valor;

                let datos = {
                    idNoticias: 0,
                    token: this.token,
                    imei: this.imei
                };

                this.LoaderNoticias();
                this.esqueletoService.CargarNoticiasGeneral(datos).then((result) => {
                    if (result != null) {
                        let codigoError = result.toString().split('|');

                        if (codigoError[0] == "777") {
                            this.loadingController.dismiss();
                            this.cards = result;
                        }
                        else if (codigoError[0] == "305") {
                            this.loadingController.dismiss();
                            this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias", "", codigoError[2]);
                        }
                        else if (codigoError[0] == "310") {
                            this.loadingController.dismiss();
                            this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias", "", codigoError[2]);
                        }
                        else if (codigoError[0] == "315") {
                            this.loadingController.dismiss();
                            this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias", "", codigoError[2]);
                        }
                        else if (codigoError[0] == "000") {
                            this.loadingController.dismiss();
                            this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias", "", "Estimado usuario, hubo un error inesperado.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        this.loadingController.dismiss();
                        this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias", "", "Estimado usuario, hubo un error inesperado.");
                    }
                }, (err) => {
                    this.loadingController.dismiss();
                    this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias", "", "Estimado usuario, hubo un error inesperado.");
                });
            }).catch(error => {
                this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias", "", "Hubo un problema al obtener los datos del usuario.");
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            this.MostrarAlerta("Noticias", "", "Hubo un problema al obtener los datos del usuario.");
        });
    });
}
```